# Override property with my profile dev in Spring Boot 2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I tried to ovveride the property

```
kafka.servers=s101lbakafpep1:9092,s102lbakafpep2:9092,s101lbakafpep3:9092
```

defined in my **src/main/resources/config/application-kafka.properties** file

with this value

```
kafka.servers=localhost:9092
```

defined in my **src/main/resources/application-dev.properties** file

I tried every combination possible reading the spring boot doc changing in my application.properties the order of

```
spring.profiles.active=config,health,planete,dgfip,mapping,kafka,dev
spring.profiles.active=dev,config,health,planete,dgfip,mapping,kafka
```

using spring.config.use-legacy-processing to true or false or .include, it's always the kafka config that wins

It's not working since i changed spring boot version to 2.4

Comment: Where is the active profile property defined? How are you starting your application?

Comment: Sorry just seen the answer to my first question. Have you tried activating a single profile or activating the profiles with a command line argument?

Comment: @burm87 i start my app with intellij, i tried to add the dev profil with the method setAdditionalProfiles, if i had only dev profile it's ok

Comment: Can you see the log line of the active profile in the logs? Are you sure all the names are correct? Actually, I've just noticed you -kafka file and your -dev file are in two different folders, have you tried putting them in the same one?

Comment: yes i see the profile names in the log file and i also tried putting them in the same folder...

Comment: This is everything I can think of. Hard to do remote debugging :)

Comment: It's working again with spring-boot 2.5.6, so it was fixed in 2.5.x

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the very helpful hint @gviczai, solved my problem loading and overriding configs from YAML files.
I completely missed the following sentence in the documentation which made my unit tests fail because values have not been overridden as it was the case with Spring Boot 2.3.

> Imports can be considered as additional documents **inserted just below the document that declares them**. They follow the same top-down ordering as regular multi-document
> files: An import will only be imported once, no matter how many times it is declared.

So if you want to override imported values a new document has to be started after the import (--- in yaml, #--- in properties).

```yaml
# imported-config.yaml
my-key: my-value
```

```yaml
# application.yaml
spring:
    config:
        import:
            - classpath:imported-config.yaml

# before starting a new document the value can not be modified, it would still be "my-value"
my-key: here-overriding-does-not-work
---
# after the start of the new document the value can be modified
my-key: my-overridden-value
```

Comment: This was golden!

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot 2.4, configuration file handling is completely rethought and rewritten.
Long story short: Forget the legacy profile-dependent documents. From now on, you have to use only one big application.properties file, but it can be divided into various profile-activated sections. These sections then can come from other files or even documents from URLs - see cloud-config.

And the main rule is: definitions BELOW always overwrite definitions ABOVE. So be careful with the order the sections (thus profiles) follow each other! ;)

You can separate the sections with "#---" and you can define which profile activates the section by providing "spring.config.activate.on-profile=<your_profile>"

So, in your case your application.properties should look like this:

```
my.property=anything
...
server.name=myserver
#in your 'default' section, you can activate any profile, so it will be active by default
spring.profiles.active=kafka
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=kafka
spring.config.import=application-kafka.properties
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
spring.config.import=application-dev.properties
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=cloud
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://my.config.server:8080/cloud-config
```

Of course, you can use yaml file if you prefer. In this case the document separator is the standard "---".

Read more about this new paradigm of config file processing here: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4

(And I guess 'kafka' profile wins over 'dev' because 'k' is AFTER 'd' in the abc... BTW, I think it is better not to name the imported documents according to the legacy profile-dependent "application-<profile>.properties" naming convention, because it may interfere with the profile-handling code. Better to be safe than sorry.)

Tip: Note, that in the same 'document' (a section in the same file considered a document) even the spring.config.import can overwrite previous values. So if you need to import multiple sources within the same section, use a comma-separated list:

```
spring.config.import=classpath:config/kafka.properties,classpath:db/postgres.properties
```

Comment: This is not true, the profile-specific properties are automatically imported from corresponding profiles:

````
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
spring.config.import=application-dev.properties
````

is redundant. You just can't add active  profiles from profile-specific file.

Comment: Correct, my bad. I myself also recognized this redundancy since then. However, I don't update my comment, so everybody can see it in its original form you referenced to.

Answer (score 0):

they're not in the same folder and the run configuration probably indicates /config for the scan.

Answer (score 0):

It's working again with spring-boot 2.5.6, so it was fixed in 2.5.x